# How to refresh ActiveInspector?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I changed the sender data in the currently open mail.

This is well done by the following code:

```
Sub AktiveMailSetVonHotline() 
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
  oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Hotline@mycompany.de"
End Sub`
```

I cannot see that the sender is set as desired. For this, I'd like to refresh the visible Mail (inspector window).

Comment: I grab an email in a public Folder and then usually simply hit reply - but the mail is supposed to be sent on behalf of "Hotline@... "  I can set this quickly with the code above. However I do not see any Change in the Outlook window - it still Displays my personal email adress there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class which allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. For example:

```
 Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
    oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
    oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
    oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
    oMail.Send 
   End If 
  Next 
 End Sub
```

Comment: If you are setting SentOnBehalfOfName  to a name of another Exchange object on whose behalf you can send, there is no separate Account object to use when setting the SendUsingAccount  property.

Comment: At the moment we don't know what exactly the poster intended to do. May be there is no need to use the SentOnBehalfOfName property at all.

Comment: I think there is no Need to Access the other account (in my case)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the From label shows the right value, you need to set the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.